# What does getHandlerId() do and how to use it?

Tags: react-dnd

Some of the `react-dnd` examples use a `getHandlerId()` method.

For example in the simple example of a sortable list, the [Card.tsx](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/blob/main/packages/examples/src/04-sortable/simple/Card.tsx) function:

- Collects a `handlerId` from the `monitor` object within the `useDrop` method

  ```
  collect(monitor) {
    return {
      handlerId: monitor.getHandlerId(),
    }
  },
  ```
- Returns that as an element of the "collected props"

  ```
  const [{ handlerId }, drop] = useDrop<
  ```
- Uses it to initialize an HTML attribute named `data-handler-id`

  ```
  <div ref={ref} style={{ ...style, opacity }} data-handler-id={handlerId}>
  ```

What is this Id and why is it used?

What uses the `data-handler-id` attribute?

I'd expect to see `getHandlerId()` described in the API documentation as a method of the [DropTargetMonitor](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/api/drop-target-monitor) (but it isn't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't dive deep into it but for me this information was enough to continue using it:

1. If you remove this data-handler-id, everything continue working but with some issues (item sometimes flickers, it doesn't go to another place as smoothly as it does with data-handler-id)
2. Here is an open issue https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/issues/2621 about low performance, and this comment suggests to use handler id: https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/issues/2621#issuecomment-847316022
3. As you can see in code https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/search?q=handlerId&type=code, handler id is using for proper definition of drop item so it seems better to use it even if you don't have a lot of elements.